# C# (2015 .NetFramework4.6)のEntity FrameworkのJoinして入手したデータのカラム数が多いのでテーブル名で指定したい

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Entity Frameworkでjoinした結果を取得したいのですが、結果として取得したデータのカラム数が多く、記述を簡潔にしたいと思います。
moneyとCashというテーブルをJoinした場合に
結果セットのうちCashテーブルのカラムだけを取り出したいのですが、何かいい書き方は無いでしょうか

```
    var addData = context.Maney.Where(n=>n.DATE==date && n.CODE==Code)
        .Join(context.Cash,
       man => man.ID,
       cash => cash.ID,
       (man, cash) => new { cash.colA,cash.ColB});//★カラムがもの凄く多い
```

```
    var addData = context.Maney.Where(n=>n.DATE==date && n.CODE==Code)
        .Join(context.Cash,
       man => man.ID,
       cash => cash.ID,
       (man, cash) => new { cash.*}); //★こんなふうにまとめたい
```

```
    var addData = context.Maney.Where(n=>n.DATE==date && n.CODE==Code)
        .Join(context.Cash,
       man => man.ID,
       cash => cash.ID,
       (man, cash) => new Cash()); //★"エンティティ型または複合型 'DATABase.Cash' は LINQ to Entities クエリでは構築できません。"というエラー
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var addData = context.Maney
    .Where(n=>n.DATE==date && n.CODE==Code)
    .Join(context.Cash,
        man => man.ID,
        cash => cash.ID,
        (man, cash) => cash);
```

これでいけないでしょうか？

```
var addData = context.Cash
    .Where(cash => context.Maney.Any(man => man.ID==cash.ID && man.DATE==date && man.CODE==Code));
```

とかでもいけるかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。最初ので行けたのでそのまま使わせていただきます